# How to label a pie chart with names and values?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have this code to plot a pie chart:

```py
// This code is pandas.plot.pie documentation
    import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"mass": [0.330, 4.87, 5.97], "radius": [2439.7, 6051.8, 6378.1]},
    index=["Mercury", "Venus", "Earth"],
)
    
plot = df.plot.pie(y="mass", figsize=(5, 5), ylabel="", autopct="%.f%%")
```

I know how show the legend. I want show numeric values along with the legend.

What is the best way to show values (in this case, radius) as part of the pie chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by setting labels with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) of [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
df.plot.pie(
    y="mass",
    figsize=(5, 5),
    autopct="%.f%%",
    legend=False,
    ylabel="",
    labels=[f"{i} ({r})" for i, r in zip(df.index, df["radius"])],
)
```

Output:

[image]